# twitter hashtag query doesn't return media entities, why?

Tags: javascript, json, twitter

i have a question please, i am trying to retrieve a json structure from twitter, if retrieve tweets from hashtag then media_entities won't work... if i retieve tweets based on user then media entities will appear...

let me eplain, if i insert:

https://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=alessandronoe&include_entities=true (it works, i see the media_url link)

if i insert : https://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23wearetwo&include_entities=true (media entities won't appear)

Is this something to do with twitter or i'm doing something wrong?

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search query should be url encoded

you should make query like https://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=@wearetwo&include_entities=true

refer the docs  https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search

Comment: Thanks for the reply..
I just used this form of search and i got results: http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=wearetwo&lang=en&result_type=recent&rpp=100&include_entities=true

can you please tell me how would i start with retrieving information? i mean how should i start retrieving image url's?

Comment: go through link http:  //www.queness.com/post/8567/create-a-dead-simple-twitter-feed-with-jquery

Comment: Yeah, i've seen that but i want to retrieve tweets from a hashtag query..i need media_url and i couldn't put it to work with the link you told me...

Comment: oh i couldn't able to do that if you find any solution kindly post that here

Comment: hey listen you are trying to get the tweets for #alessandronoe  hashtag which is not a hash tags actually while you are searching  alessandronoe  then twitter is searching that as a string  so make sure if you are doing query for a hashtag  it should be available on twitter  got it . you will definetly get the results for                                                                               https://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=#iphone&include_entities=true    because #iphone is a hashtag